# Intent losing data when scrolling Recycler View

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, scroll, android-viewholder

I am trying to send some texts from a Recycler View to another Activity, and it works fine when the screen isn't scrolled to the bottom.
But when i scroll down, some data from the Intent is lost. This doesn't happens when I scroll up and click in the buttons.

The favorite button code is from [here.](https://github.com/IvBaranov/MaterialFavoriteButton)

[image: Not working]

[image: Working]

My Adapter code:

```
public class AdapterLanches extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterLanches.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {

public static MaterialFavoriteButton favoriteButton;
private List<Lanches> listaLanches;
private List<Lanches> listaLanchesCompleta;
public static Lanches itemAtual;
ArrayList<CharSequence> favoritos;
boolean fav = false;

int estadoPrograma;
public Button lc,fit;

int posicao = -1;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public MaterialFavoriteButton favoriteButton;
    TextView titulo;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;


    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        lc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lc);
        fit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fit);
        favoriteButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favorite);

        favoriteButton.setOnFavoriteChangeListener(new MaterialFavoriteButton.OnFavoriteChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFavoriteChanged(MaterialFavoriteButton buttonView, boolean favorite) {
               final int posicao = getAdapterPosition();
                fav = favorite;
                favoritos.add(listaLanchesCompleta.get(posicao).getTitulo());
                VeganoActivity.intentLanches2.putExtra("titulo", favoritos);
                System.out.println(favoritos);

            }
        });

        titulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textnomeLanchesId);
        favoritos = new ArrayList<>();

    }
}


public AdapterLanches(List<Lanches> listaLanches) {


    this.listaLanches = listaLanches;
    listaLanchesCompleta = new ArrayList<>(this.listaLanches);

}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return lanchesFilter;
}

public Filter lanchesFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        List<Lanches> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
            filteredList.addAll(listaLanchesCompleta);
        }else{
            estadoPrograma = 1;
            String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for ( Lanches item : listaLanchesCompleta){
                if (item.getTitulo().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)){
                    filteredList.add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        results.values = filteredList;
        results.count = filteredList.size();

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        listaLanches.clear();
        listaLanches.addAll((ArrayList<Lanches>)results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};


@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemListaLanches = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_lanches, parent, false);
    final MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(itemListaLanches);




    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    itemAtual = listaLanches.get(position);
    holder.titulo.setText(itemAtual.getTitulo());


    if (itemAtual.getId() == 0){
        fit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (itemAtual.getId() == 1){
        lc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (itemAtual.getId() == 2){
        fit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return listaLanches.size();
}
```

}

Any help is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list that gives those data wider scope. Because the RecyclerView is going to wipe them when their out of view.

```
var stuffINeedToKeep=mutableListOf<String>()//this goes right under the class constructor so that it has wide scope
...
heart.setOnClickListener({
stuffINeedToKeep.add(dataFromViewHolder)
})
```

Comment: ArrayList<CharSequence> favoritos;
               and
favoritos.add(listaLanchesCompleta.get(posicao).getTitulo());

Isn't already doing that?

Comment: I don't know if this is what caused the problem, but I think it's a bad idea to reinstantiate favoritos on every single onCreateViewHolder

Comment: But it is in MyViewHolder constructor, not OnBindViewHolder
There is a better place you think i can put it in?

Comment: I see that, but it's called from onCreateViewHolder and you don't have very fine control over when that gets dispatched. I've never had any problems with the following recyclerview workflow. I define the dataset that will control the adapter completely outside the recyclerview giving it activity-level scope. Then I populate it during oncreate. If I'm getting the contents from a server, I'll populate it with a pagified query and do the first call from oncreate. Then I pass that dataset into the constructor of the adapter. Easy to read and change the dataset and call notify() when I change it.